# Writing line by line to gzip file

Tags: bash, file, concatenation, gzip

I'm working with large data (millions of lines).

I have a COTS script that generates these lines, and I need to annotate the lines by content into different files. Because of the size of the files as pure text, it would be ideal if data could be written directly in gzip format.

I.e.

```
line_generator | while read line; do
  [[ $line =~ .*0/0.* ]] && { echo "${#line}," | gzip -9 >> REF.out.gz ; }
  [[ $line =~ .*0/1.* ]] && { echo "${line}" | gzip -9 >> MAT.out.gz ; }
  [[ $line =~ .*1/0.* ]] && { echo "${line} | sed 's/X/y/g'" | gzip -9 >> MAT.out.gz ; }
done
```

Again, because of the extreme file sizes and line counts, I'm not sure I can build the files in memory first, before dumping out to a GZIP'ped file.

Comment: Use on-the-fly compressing filesystem, i.g. btrfs with gzip compression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forking a copy `gzip` separately for each line. That's not a very good idea, as it's slow and the compression suffers from that, since all lines are compressed as independent blocks. With short lines, the result is probably longer than the uncompressed version...

But, you can open the pipes once using `exec` and [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), and then keep writing to them during the loop (exec with a command replaces the shell, but without a command, any [redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirections) take place in the shell process). For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3> >(gzip -9 >> odd.out.gz)
exec 4> >(gzip -9 >> even.out.gz)

seq 1 1000 | while read x ; do 
        [[ $x =~ [13579]$ ]] && echo "$x" >&3
        [[ $x =~ [02468]$ ]] && echo "$x" >&4
done 
# close the pipes when you're done
exec 3>&-
exec 4>&-
```

Comment: BRILLIANT! Thx!